# Selecting date ranges that do not include today

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a database table with two columns, `startDate` and `endDate`.

I'm trying to select date ranges that DO NOT have today's date in them. Can't figure out how to do it

```
SELECT startDate, endDate
FROM table
WHERE now() NOT BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
```

I know the `WHERE` syntax above is completely wrong but I'm including it so you can get an idea of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What are the data types for `startDate` and `endDate`?

Comment: are your start end endate columsn date or datetime?

Answer (score 0):

May not work as requested as I am not 100 percent sure on the strictness of your start and end date

```
SELECT startDate, endDate 
FROM myTable
WHERE startDate > CURDATE() OR endDate < CURDATE()
```

Alternatively try putting CURDATE into your orignal post instead of NOW

Comment: his query doesn't work. It does not return the right dates. I have a table of room bookings. I want to select the days that do not have a booking. How can I do that?

Comment: That query is invalid syntax. Escape `table` with backticks.

Comment: in coldfusion we don't use backticks so its not necessary.

Comment: If your startDate is always less than your endDate then the above query will return the correct results.  Provide data and examples of the fault for evaluation.  All possible examples function under this query

Answer (score 0):

If you meant does not include the current date and time, your query was 100% correct, except that `table` needs to have backticks around it.

If you literally meant date, and not datetime,

```
SELECT startDate, endDate
FROM `table`
WHERE CURDATE() + 1<= startDate OR CURDATE() > endDate
```

This query will exclude any range that includes any part of today.

Comment: I meant date not time. This query doesn't work. It does not return the right dates. I have a table of room bookings. I want to select the days that do not have a booking. How can I do that?